# JAVA - receiving objects using sockets and threads not working

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, socket.io, client-server

I'm trying to get an object from the server, but it does not work.

Relevant section from the server (By Debug I see that he is really sending the correct object):

```
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
    launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
    mainPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
    mainPane.setPadding(new Insets(5,5,5,5));

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
    gridPane.add(lblStatus,0,1);
    gridPane.add(lblDate,0,2);  

    mainPane.setTop(gridPane);
    createTableView();
    mainPane.setCenter(tableView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 700, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Server"); // Set the window title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the window
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the window
    primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true); 
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(
            new EventHandler<WindowEvent>(){
                public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                    try { 
                        Platform.exit();
                        System.exit(0);
                        serverSocket.close();
                        socket.close();
                    } 
                    catch(SocketException ex){
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Platform.exit();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            });

    connectToDB();
    connectionDate=new Date();
    Platform.runLater(() ->lblDate.setText(("Server started at \t"+connectionDate)));
    Platform.runLater(() ->lblStatus.setText(connectionStatus));
    new Thread( () ->
    { 
        try{ 
            // Create a server socket
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
            while (true){
                // Listen for a connection request
                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                this.clientNo++;
                clientRequest clientDetails = new clientRequest(clientNo, new Date(), "New Clinet");
                addRowToServerTable(clientDetails);

                new Thread(new HandleAClient(socket)).start();


            }

        }
        catch(SocketException ex){
        }
        catch(IOException ex){ 
        }

    }).start(); 
}

/** Connect to DB */
private void connectToDB(){ 

    // Connection to the database
    try{
        Class.forName(driver);                                                  // Load the JDBC driver
        System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);      // Establish a connection
        System.out.println("Connected to " + url);
        connectionStatus = "Connected to \t" + url;
    }
    catch (java.lang.Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        connectionStatus = ex.toString();
    }
}


// Define the thread class for handling new connection
class HandleAClient implements Runnable{

    private Socket socket; // A connected socket

    /** Construct a thread */
    public HandleAClient(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    /** Run a thread */
    public void run(){
        try{
            // Create data input and output streams
            ObjectOutputStream outputToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(
                    socket.getInputStream());

            // Continuously serve the client
            while (true){
                // Receive sql from the client
                String sql = inputFromClient.readUTF();

                clientRequest clientDetails = new clientRequest(clientNo, new Date(),"New Query");
                addRowToServerTable(clientDetails);

                // Execute SQL
                Object[] rows = executeSQL(sql);
                outputToClient.writeObject(rows);

            }
        }
        catch(SocketException ex){
            try{
                serverSocket.close();
                //socket.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e){ 
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){ 
        }
    }
```

Relevant section from the client (Probably the mistake on the client, when it receives the object he jumps line ".start ();" Of the Thread.):

```
    private void connectToServer(){
    try{
        // Create a socket to connect to the server
        socket = new Socket(host, 8000);
        // Create an input stream to receive Object from the server
        fromServer = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        // Create an output stream to send data to the server
        toServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void sendAndGetFromServer(String sqlQuery){
    new Thread(() ->{
        try{

            System.out.println("a1");
            // Send sql query to server
            toServer.writeUTF(sqlQuery);
            //toServer.flush();
            // Get notification from the server

            Student[] rows = (Student[])fromServer.readObject();
            setRowsInTable(rows);
        }
        catch(SocketException ex){
            try{
                socket.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e){ 
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex){
        }
    }).start();
```

I tried to separate into two Thread (One Input and other Output in Server and client) according to the answers I read here --- but it didn't help.
Also tried to change the order of Input and Output --- without success.

- No errors!
- The client don't get the object.

What's the problem here?

Edit. Student class:

```
public class Student implements  Externalizable
{ 
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty ID;
    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty address;
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<Date> birthDate;
    private final SimpleStringProperty department;
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty pointsAmount;
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<Date> startStudyingDate;
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty failedAmount;
    private final SimpleDoubleProperty average;
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty lavelByGrade;
    private final SimpleStringProperty pic;

    public Student(int ID, String firstName, String lastName, String address,
            Date  birthDate, String department,
            int pointsAmount, Date startStudyingDate, int failedAmount, 
            double average, int  lavelByGrade, String pic){

        this.ID= new SimpleIntegerProperty(ID);
        this.firstName= new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.lastName= new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
        this.address= new SimpleStringProperty(address);
        this.birthDate= new SimpleObjectProperty<Date>(birthDate);
        this.department= new SimpleStringProperty(department);
        this.pointsAmount= new SimpleIntegerProperty(pointsAmount);
        this.startStudyingDate= new  SimpleObjectProperty<Date>(startStudyingDate);
        this.failedAmount= new SimpleIntegerProperty(failedAmount);
        this.average= new SimpleDoubleProperty(average);
        this.lavelByGrade= new SimpleIntegerProperty(lavelByGrade);
        this.pic = new SimpleStringProperty(pic);
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID.get();
    }
    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID.set(ID);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address.get();
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address.set(address);
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate.get();
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate.set(birthDate);
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department.get();
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department.set(department);
    }

    public int getPointsAmount() {
        return pointsAmount.get();
    }

    public void setPointsAmount(int pointsAmount) {
        this.pointsAmount.set(pointsAmount);
    }

    public Date getStartStudyingDate() {
        return startStudyingDate.get();
    }

    public void setStartStudyingDate(Date startStudyingDate) {
        this.startStudyingDate.set(startStudyingDate);
    }

    public int getFailedAmount() {
        return failedAmount.get();
    }

    public void setFailedAmount(int failedAmount) {
        this.failedAmount.set(failedAmount);
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return average.get();
    }

    public void setAverage(Double average) {
        this.average.set(average);
    }

    public int getLavelByGrade() {
        return lavelByGrade.get();
    }

    public void setLavelByGrade(int lavelByGrade) {
        this.lavelByGrade.set(lavelByGrade);
    }

    public String getPic() {
        return pic.get();
    }

    public void setPic(String pic) {
        this.pic.set(pic);
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {

        setID(in.readInt());
        setFirstName((String)in.readObject());
        setLastName((String)in.readObject());
        setAddress((String)in.readObject());
        setBirthDate((Date)in.readObject());
        setDepartment((String)in.readObject());
        setPointsAmount(in.readInt());
        setStartStudyingDate((Date)in.readObject());
        setFailedAmount(in.readInt());
        setAverage(in.readDouble());
        setLavelByGrade(in.readInt());
        setPic((String)in.readObject());
    }

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {

        out.writeInt(getID());
        out.writeObject(getFirstName()); 
        out.writeObject(getLastName()); 
        out.writeObject(getAddress()); 
        out.writeObject(getBirthDate());
        out.writeObject(getDepartment());
        out.writeInt(getPointsAmount()); 
        out.writeObject(getStartStudyingDate()); 
        out.writeInt(getFailedAmount()); 
        out.writeDouble(getAverage()); 
        out.writeInt(getLavelByGrade());
        out.writeObject(getPic()); 

    }
}
```

Comment: just saying not working is not enough. You need to tell us why do you think its not working. Do you see any exception/error etc..

Comment: @SMA Thanks. If I get an error, of course I would have written it. Not receive an error. 'Client' just don't get the object.

Comment: Try serializating the sending object, you should have same type of object on both server and client, and for that you should also have serialize UUID object class

Comment: Does your executeSQL function actually create an array of Student or just an array of Object? You need to make sure that both, the client and the server use the exact same class. You should probably just serialize the classes before sending them.

Comment: @DoubleK like that:  public class Student implements java.io.Serializable{ private static final long serialVersionUID =-6495430644492605934L; ?

Comment: @mhlz Student class is already implements Serializable. executeSQL function create array of object (object[]).

Comment: That might be your problem then. You need to actually create a Student array if you want to recieve one.

Comment: Yes, but what is most important is that this serialVersionUID must be same on client and server, if not it won't work! In case it isn't you can manually set this number to i.e. 1 so it can be recognized (just to mention, this uid is generated by method names, class names etc when implementing Serializable so it won't be unique of classes aren't completly the same on both server and client)

Comment: @DoubleK thank. To make sure I understood you. Just add class variable to client, server and Student class? like this: private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; ?

Comment: @mhlz I create "ArrayList<Student> " and in the end of the function: Object[] studentRow = (Object[]) tempRow.toArray(); and In debug I see that he is really sending the correct object.

Comment: Yes, but don't add this variable by yourself, just implement Serializable interface (by adding implements Serializable to Student class on both server and client) and private static final long serialVersionUID = someValueL; should be generated, and if this number isn't the same on server and client change its value to 1L, it they are same leave it as it is (if they are the same by default that means that classes are completely the same, no difference in methods, variable etc and that is also ok, preferred actually). One other solution is using Gson or Jackson tokenizers/serializators

Comment: @DoubleK sorry, I don't know how do this. how I "adding implements Serializable to Student class on both server and client"? Student class is already implements Serializable, How to do it also to serve and client? Do you have an example to refer me to it?

Comment: Sorry I missed one part, I thought about my app, that you have two apps not one app with different threads. The thing is objects sent must be of same type, as @mhlz mentioned, you are sending array of Objects with this lines;  Object[] rows = executeSQL(sql); Try changing  Student[] rows = executeSQL(sql); in sending thread
                outputToClient.writeObject(rows);   and receiving Students with this line:    Student[] rows = (Student[])fromServer.readObject(); which is not the same in terms of serialization (here is not important that Students actually inherits for Object)

Comment: @DoubleK O.K why that? they can't use the same Student class? It looks strange...

Comment: sorry, my fault, I edited my comment, it can, just try to change  Object[] rows = executeSQL(sql); to  Student[] rows = executeSQL(sql);

Comment: @DoubleK  I tried. Does not help. I even created an object and sent --- fails. like that: Student[] rows= {new Student(32, "ramz", "Obama","USA", new Date(), "software",140, new Date() , 0, 100,2, "")}; outputToClient.writeObject(rows);

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting exceptions? You have an empty `catch` block corresponding to the `try` block that reads from the server, so if an exception occurred you wouldn't know about it. Put `ex.printStackTrace();` in the empty `catch` block and see if anything is generated.

Comment: @James_D thank you. Now i got exceptions. Server: "java.io.NotSerializableException: javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty". Client: "java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX properties are not Serializable. So if you try to serialize an object that uses JavaFX properties for its state, you will get an exception.

You have a couple of options here. One is simply to not use Java object serialization, but some other serialization technique, such as representing the object with JSON.

The other option is to implement `Externalizable` instead of `Serializable`. `Externalizable` is a subinterface of `Serializable` in which you define your own process for serializing and deserializing the data. In particular, instead of serializing the JavaFX properties themselves, just serialize their contents.

A simple example:

```
import java.io.Externalizable ;
import java.io.IOException ;
import java.io.ObjectInput ;
import java.io.ObjectOutput ;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty ;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty ;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty ;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty ;

public class Person implements Externalizable {

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name ;
    }
    public final String getName() {
        return nameProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setName(String name) {
        nameProperty().set(name);
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id ;
    }
    public final int getId() {
        return idProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setId(int id) {
        idProperty().set(id);
    }

    // important: must have a no-arg constructor:
    public Person() { }

    public Person(int id, String name) {
        setId(id);
        setName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        // write id then name
        // note we write the contents of the properties, not the properties 
        // themselves, as the properties are not serializable:
        out.writeInt(getId());
        out.writeObject(getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // read data back in same order:
        setId(in.readInt());
        setName((String)in.readObject());
    }
}
```

Note that this class has a pretty simple structure, so it's easy to implement these two methods. For more complex objects - particularly those which may potentially have circular references - you need to work a bit harder.

Since the class defined above implements `Externalizable`, it also implements `Serializable`, and can be serialized in the usual way:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = ... ;
oos.writeObject(new Person(007, "James Bond"));
```

Read my blog post on [JavaFX beans and JPA](http://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2014/05/09/one-bean-to-bind-them-all/) for more.

Comment: Thank you. I did it, and now I got this exception: "java.io.InvalidClassException: javaNetFinal.Student; no valid constructor". Do you know why? I added the updated class to the question...

Comment: You need a zero-argument constructor. (You'll need it to initialize all your FX properties to "empty" properties, eg `this.ID = new SimpleIntegerProperty();`)

Comment: thank you so much! it's work. I don't understand why need empty constructor?  if I don't use it.

Comment: It's used when the object is deserialized. See the [`Externalizable` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this post, search part with following text and Externalizable:    For quite a long time, I thought the lack of support for Serialization from JavaFX properties really prevented them from being used in any server-side capacity.

http://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2014/05/09/one-bean-to-bind-them-all/

https://gist.github.com/james-d/e485ac525c71e20bb453

Comment: While I appreciate the links, link-only answers are generally discouraged on SO as the links have a tendency to go stale. It's fine to link for more details or further information, but the answer should stand alone as an answer to the question.