# JavaFx, application don't add information

Tags: javafx

I am doing program similar on ContactList, but when I try to add information, I can't see my information. But if I do nine clicks, I can see scrolling.
I have my work file, end prtsc fxml file below.

```
 @FXML
  private void initialize() throws IOException {
    iniData();
    id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Work, Integer>("id"));
    Fname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Work, String>("fname"));
    Lname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Work, String>("lname"));
    Phone.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Work, String>("phone"));
    Email.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Work, String>("email"));
    table.setItems(arr);

    addName.setPromptText("fname");
    addName.setMaxWidth(Fname.getPrefWidth());
    addLName.setPromptText("lname");
    addLName.setMaxWidth(Lname.getPrefWidth());
    addPhone.setPromptText("phone");
    addPhone.setMaxWidth(Phone.getPrefWidth());
    addEmail.setPromptText("email");
    addEmail.setMaxWidth(Email.getPrefWidth());
btn01.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        arr.add(new Work(addName.getText(),
                addLName.getText(), addPhone.getText(), addEmail.getText()));
    }    }    );        }

public void iniData() throws IOException {
    arr.add(new Work(1, "Alex", "qwerty", "33333","alex@mail.com"));
    arr.add(new Work(2, "Bob", "dsfsdfw","0987432", "bob@mail.com"));
    arr.add(new Work(3, "Jeck", "dsfdsfwe","345743", "Jeck@mail.com"));
    arr.add(new Work(4, "Mike", "iueern","32456", "mike@mail.com"));
    arr.add(new Work(5, "colin", "woeirn","12233455", "colin@mail.com"));
}}
```

My Work java file.

```
    public class Work implements Serializable{
    private Integer id;
    private String Fname;
    private String Lname;
    private String Phone;
    private String Email;
    private String addFname;
    private String addLname;
    private String addPhone;
    private String addEmail;



    public Work(Integer id, String fname, String lname, String phone, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        Fname = fname;
        Lname = lname;
        Phone = phone;
        Email = email;
    }

    public Work(String addFname, String addLname, String addPhone, String addEmail) {
        this.addFname = addFname;
        this.addLname = addLname;
        this.addPhone = addPhone;
        this.addEmail = addEmail;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return Fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        Fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return Lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        Lname = lname;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        Phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public String getAddFname() {
        return addFname;
    }

    public void setAddFname(String addFname) {
        this.addFname = addFname;
    }

    public String getAddLname() {
        return addLname;
    }

    public void setAddLname(String addLname) {
        this.addLname = addLname;
    }

    public String getAddPhone() {
        return addPhone;
    }

    public void setAddPhone(String addPhone) {
        this.addPhone = addPhone;
    }

    public String getAddEmail() {
        return addEmail;
    }

    public void setAddEmail(String addEmail) {
        this.addEmail = addEmail;
    }
}
```

[this is the link to view fxml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbPgv.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the `Work` class?

Answer (score 0):

As your not using properties in your Work class you have to set the cell like

```
FName.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Work, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
 public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Work, String> p) {
     return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getFname());
 }
```

});

As an alternate you could use properties but aus they are not serializable you have to override the functions for reading and writing object as discribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763181/java-receiving-objects-using-sockets-and-threads-not-working/28766315#28766315)